# Nested views with *ngFor in ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I would like to create a screen that contains nested views with *ngFor loop. There is an 2 dimensional array data that needs to be iterated to repeat the same view for each of the row for every section. It may appear as follows:

```
(SectionName 1)
      Row1
      Row2
(SectionName 2)
      Row1
      Row2
```

Each row can be created using ion-item with buttons and input boxes.

Please let me know how to create 2 dimensional repeated UI.

Thanks,

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and share some code that you already tried.

Answer (score 1):

Hey you should definitely describe in details what you are trying to accomplish as it leaves a lot of space for interpretation.

My naive understanding based on what you want is below:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-boxpjy

for the following array:

```
array = [
    ["section 1 item 1", "section 1 item 2", "section 1 item 3"],
    ["section 2 item 1", "section 2 item 2", "section 2 item 3", "section 2 item 4"],
  ]
```

[image]